# Casting and pointer casting in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, lvalue, rvalue

Can anyone explain me why this is true:

```
char *p;
short  i;
long l;

(long *) p = &l ;       /* Legal cast   */
(long) i = l ;          /* Illegal cast */
```

I know it has something to do with lvalue and rvalue but shouldn't `(long *) p` be a rvalue?

**edit:**

sorry it seems I confused myself and others, I asked this while reading ["this MDSN"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx) and I was surprised to see this syntax, I see it's a special feature that allows to convert lvalue into lvalue as long as it's the same size.

Comment: Neither are valid C++, and this shouldn't compile. The result of either cast is an rvalue to which you cannot assign.

Comment: Neither of these compile for me.

Comment: Well, I don't see how (1) is legal. According to my `clang++`, it's not. They both are erroneous.

Comment: Regarding the edit: That's just plain weird. If the two types have the same size, then why not just say `p = (char *) &l`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these expressions are legal, they should both fail to compile.

C++11, 5.17.1:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

5.4:

> Explicit type conversion (cast notation) [expr.cast]
>   1 The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to object type; otherwise the result is a prvalue.

So both expressions violate these constraints.

Answer (score 2):

> shouldn't (long *) p be a rvalue?

**It is.**

They're both prvalues and, as such, *both* statements are ill-formed:

> `[C++03: 5.4/1]:` **The result of the expression `(T)` *cast-expression*** is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if `T` is a reference type, otherwise the result **is an rvalue**.
>
> `[C++11: 5.4/1]:` **The result of the expression `(T)` *cast-expression*** is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type; otherwise the result **is a prvalue**. *[..]*

[GCC 4.8 rejects your "legal cast"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdec1e9db0026232), but [Visual Studio has an extension that accepts this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx) (for no apparent reason).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think your cast is legal? I'm getting `error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value` on both casts.

This shouldn't be legal. If you really want to do it, you have to cast it like this:

```
(long*&)p = &l; // equivalent to *(long**)&p = &l
```

But don't do that unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: When you know what you are doing, you don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a value conversion is an rvalue. You cannot assign to rvalues of fundamental types.

In other words, for `int a = 10;`, `a` is an lvalue of type `int`, but `(long) a` is a temporary rvalue of type `long`, and you cannot assign to the temporary. Likewise for pointers.